# Up/Downstream Bandwidth Requirements for Xbox Live Multiplayer Games

Tags: xbox-network, voice-chat

In terms of upstream and downstream, about how much bandwidth does Xbox Live require for games like Black Ops, while using the VoIP feature with friends?

Comment: This is pretty subjective and based on many peoples experience/opinions, you'll likely get a lot of different answers. I'm on a 7Mbps down/512Kbps upload cable connection, and it works great for multiplayer and chat. Hosted games just fine. Latency is a factor in this as well as well as your network setup. Make sure other people on your network aren't hogging bandwidth up with Netflix streaming, torrents, etc. I wouldn't go with a mobile 4g connection or satellite either.

Comment: I should have phrased the question differently. I have 15MBps down and 768kbps up, everything works fine. I'm asking because I was to know what kind of limits to set in my torrent client.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I would suggest just throttling the uploading on it while playing and test a few scenarios, see which works out best.

Answer (score 2):

Probably at least about 1MBps download and 512KBps upload. But if you are hosting the game i recommend that you have at least 2MBps download and 1MBps upload, in case many people join and lag your whole network.

Comment: Not going to downvote this, but I think the 1MBps is way too high a minimum for hosting. On a 512Kbps upload connection myself and have hosted decent sized games just fine. Latency is also a factor to consider (don't use satellite or mobile 4g connections).

Comment: I agree with Blake. My original connection was 512kbps on the upside and haven't had any problems. I have a bit more now, 768kbps, which I know is more than enough. I just want to know what a good limit is for my torrent client.

Comment: it probably depends on your location. i had 512kbps upload speed and it was rather slow, until i upgraded to one with a 1mbps upload speed

Answer (score 1):

The bandwidth requirements are so minimal that you should not even think about it. Your average connection (DSL/Cable) will be able to handle it no problem. If you are on a slower connection, can you use other XBOX Live features? If yes, you will be safe to try gaming too. The games don't actually send/receive much more data than the dashboard believe it or not.

If you want hard numbers, the only way to know for sure is to use a network monitor between your Internet connection and XBOX. This will give you exact measurements of the requirements. Be aware though, this will differ between games, game types, and other factors like number of players, whether you are hosting the game or not, and if you are using other XBOX features like Party chat and such.

Comment: 'so minimal that you should not even think about it' for you can often mean 'unusable' for others (such as myself).  However, I will admit that when I had xbox live Gold, online gameplay worked better than I was expecting *most of the time*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have DSL, you don't need to switch providers. The best thing you could do is request your DSL provider to remove interleaving from your line if it exists. This will give you what they call a "fast path" connection. Fast path reduces lag or ping time by as much as 30 milliseconds because it bypasses some error checking of the data. If you ask for it and they say your line isn't stable enough then tell them you want a tech out to adjust your connection on their equipment (somewhere in you neighborhood). Once your line is optimized, they will remove interleaving at your request.